# Eigenvalues of a 2x2 matrix A such that $A^2$=I

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have no idea where to begin.

Let A be a $2\times 2$ matrix such that $A^2= I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.  Find all the eigenvalues of $A$.

I know there are a few matrices that support this claim, will they all have the same eigenvalues?

Comment: Hint: If A were diagonal (say) what could you say about the eigenvalues? Now if A were any matrix you could conjugate it to something upper triangular, call it B. But B will also satisfy $B^{2} = I$ . This should then tell you everything.

Comment: No, they don't all have the same eigenvalues.  But the number of possibilities is small.

Comment: That the eigenvalues are the values on the main diagonal, either -1 or 1?  And if B is an upper triangular matrix, the determinant is the eigenvalues again with the values of the diagnal

Comment: Do you know about the minimal polynomial?

Answer (score 7):

If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $$v=Iv=A^2v=A(Av)=A(\lambda v)=\lambda(Av)=\lambda^2 v.$$
Thus, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $A^2=I$ then $\lambda^2=1$.  This gives only two possibilities for $\lambda$, $\pm 1$.

Notice, that we never assumed that $A$ is $2\times 2$.  Indeed, if $A$ is any square matrix and $A^2=I$ then the only possible eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $A$ be an arbitrary $2\times 2$ matrix, and $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$
Then we have:
$$A^2=I\Longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}a^2+bc&ab+bd\\ac+cd&bc+d^2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
Therefore, any matrix of the form:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&-a\end{pmatrix}\text{ or }A=\begin{pmatrix}\pm1&0\\0&\pm1\end{pmatrix}$$
will satisfy the condition $A^2=I$. In the first case its eigenvalues are then given by:
$$\begin{vmatrix}a-\lambda&b\\c&-a-\lambda\end{vmatrix}=0\Longrightarrow \lambda^2=a^2+bc=1$$
Therefore $\lambda=\pm 1$. The second case also gives us $\lambda=\pm1$.

Comment: What if $A$ is $10\times 10$?  This method seems un-necessarily hard.

Comment: @TravisJ Sure, your method is generalized to any $n\times n$ matrix. But OP is specifically asking about $2\times 2$ matrices, for which this method does work and in all honesty, is not too hard.

Comment: @Demosthene, yes, for $2\times 2$ it is ok, and that's what was asked.  I wasn't saying there was anything wrong, just that it is harder than necessary.

Comment: @TravisJ Of course, of course. Brute force should only be acceptable in low order cases like this one. Expand your answer and I'll +1 it.

Comment: @TravisJ Being able to brute force an answer rather than relying on shortcuts is an important skill to have.

Comment: @DanielV, I don't know if I'd call it a shortcut, it is just an different way of interpreting what the eigenvalues are.  Both methods certainly have value.  Whenever you can view a problem/solution from multiple directions it is beneficial.  It allows you to see advantages and disadvantages of the methods.